# Kernel security patches are not needed in Docker containers?

Tags: ubuntu, security, docker

The host and the Docker container use the same kernel, so applying the security patch to the host should be enough, right?

Example: the CVE-2021-33909 vunerability: https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2021-33909. On Ubuntu, running `apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade && reboot` on the **host** is enough?

Comment: Are you running those commands in a container or on the host?  If it installed a new kernel, did you reboot?

Comment: On the host, and yes for the reboot, I'll clarify that.

Comment: If, after the reboot a `uname -r` shows the new kernel version, then you're running the updated kernel.  Since the host and containers share the same kernel, that applies to the containers too.

Comment: I tried and yes, the kernel versions for the host and container are in sync, before and after updating the host. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Containers share the same kernel as the host, so if you successfully update the kernel on the host and reboot into that kernel, both the host and the containers will use the new kernel.  You won't have to explicitly update anything within any container.